# Condition on a sequence to generate an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

That conditions are necessary and sufficient for the succession $\{ \beta_n\}$ for the infinite product
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \sin(\beta_n z) }{\beta_n z}  $$

converges an entire function.

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Comment: What assumptions are we given for the $\beta_n$?  Can they be any complex numbers?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Yes, of course $\{ \beta_n \} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I can see how one could argue that a necessary and sufficient condition is $\sum_n |\beta_n|^2 < \infty$.  But I can only see how to make it work if $\beta_n$ is restricted to be a real number.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer (in the case $\beta_n \in \mathbb R$):

Since
$\frac{\sin(\beta_n z)}{\beta_n z} = 1 - \frac{(\beta_n z)^2}6 + O((\beta_n z)^4)$,
and for $\alpha_n > 0$, $\prod_n (1-\alpha_n)$ converges to something other than zero if and only if $\sum_n\alpha_n < \infty$, it suggests that $\sum_n |\beta_n|^2 < \infty$ might be the condition.

If $\beta_n$ is not restricted to be real, I can see a possible way to show this condition is sufficient, but I don't see right now how to show that this condition is necessary.

Comment: Oh yes. you are right. Thanks.